# No connection (#2002) Error connecting to MySQL DB from one IP, but works from another IP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a LAMP server hosted on Amzaon AWS and using php to connect and insert values to a MySQL DB on that remote server.  (https://studio.hamlethub.com/belocal/final.php)

When I access this form from my office, everything works perfectly.  However, from my home, I am receiving an error: **No connection (#2002)**.

I am able to access phpmyadmin successfully from both places, both IP's.  I checked the error log and do not see any issues.

What could it be inside of my php that could prevent a successful connection based on the local IP, when I am not using a local server?

Ken

Comment: Thanks, I read that link.  The phpmyadmin software and the php program I am using (final.php) are both located on the same server. So aren't both connecting the same IP, the server IP?

Comment: Oh, I misread, both connections should be from the server, not your local IP (unless the IP is in the connection request?)

Comment: Ouch! Sorry, I am using php form builder and did not realize they had a customized setting to connect.  The issue was a local config as you suggested!

Answer (score 1):

There was an IP in the connection request.  I am using PHP form builder which has a setting in the db-connect.php file which needed to be customized.